# Biztalk FlatFile fill node with NULL values

Tags: encoding, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I'm somehow stuck with the following problem:

I have a schema where I need to count the length of the first part of the message cause it has a dynamic length, and at the end fill it up with NULL's until I reach 256 Byte blocks.

So I thought I could count the length of the string input from the first part and then just fill it up with a function like this:

```
 public string GetHexNulls(string val)
    {

        var b = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 256 - val.Length; i++)
        {
           b.Append(0.ToString("X"));   
        }

        return b.ToString();
    }
```

I can't manage to get NULLs (HEX 0x00) but normal string zeros (HEX 0x30). Is it clear what my problem is?

I'm not sure how to achieve this - or more general, how to print out HEX values to a text file which are recognized as HEX values. I guess this all about encoding?

Comment: Well, keep in mind, the 'hex' part doesn't really matter.  Null is char 0 no matter how it's expressed.  Are you sure you can't just use the Pad Character = 0x00?

Comment: Yea normally i would use the pad char as this works as expected in a positional flat file but in this case i need a dynamic size for the node. How to achieve that?

Comment: But 'fill to the end' implies a fixed width?

Comment: I guess, how could i tell the ff assambler to fill it up to 256 Bytes if i don't have a positional file and the size is dynamic? I might set up the pad character but how to determine the size?

Comment: It looks like you could write out the right character representation within a string but the ff assembler seems to not allow it? 

Following updated method:
`...
b.Append('\u0000'); 
...`

produces the following error:
`Error 13 XSL transform error: Unable to write output instance to the following <file:///C:file.xml>. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.`

Comment: Regardless of the individual fields, you're saying the row you need to pad is fixed at 256 chars?

Comment: No sry, that was a misunderstanding - The whole parent node (which has some children, each with a dynamic size) has to be 256 chars long. So the  last child node, can't have a fixed size

Comment: @Johns-305 thank you very much for your support! Seems like I'm not getting over this just like that. How about a custom pipeline to achieve this?

Comment: Is the whole message fixed at 256 bytes or each row is 256 total?  That's what I'm missing.

Comment: each row is 256 total with n rows

Comment: How many fields are we talking about per row? 5 or 50?

Comment: As the other fields are dynamic in size, I take it those are delimited fields?

Comment: 8 delimited Fields per row.

Answer (score 0):

As the other fields are dynamic in size, then those fields must be delimited

What can do is concatenate the fields together with your delimiter in a map into a single field on which you set the *Minimum Length with Pad Character* to 256 and *Pad Character* to 0x00 and *Pad Character Type* to Hexadecimal.

[image: Null Padding Properties]

Comment: That really is a way to solve the problem. I didn't think about it that way. The only thing i don't like, you have everything in one filed. That messes up the schema and it just looks somehow ugly to store everything in one field. I'll check my pipeline approach let you know how this works!

Comment: In my first post, i haven't mentioned that also need to set some hex pad characters in the first message part. These pad characters define regions with a start and end block. So this won't work. I can't store everything in one field as i need defined fields for the pad characters.

Comment: @Megalomaniac  Then you had better update your question using the [edit] link giving all the details, we can't really help you if you only give us part of the problem.   Give us a sample input & input schema and expected output.